# Canvas isn't updating

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was planning on making a personal project with `JavaScript` until I encountered a problem. I have a canvas representing the HP 
but it's not updating, I've tried Intervals but it didn't work either.

Code below:

```
<script>

var health=100;
var h = health;
var totalhealth=100;
var intNumber;

function hp(){
     var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
     var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);

     grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
     grd.addColorStop(0.2,"#F4710E");
     grd.addColorStop(1,"green");

     ctx.fillStyle=grd;
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,(h/100)*140,10);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = h +"/"+totalhealth;
}

function punch(){
     health-=1;
}

</script>
```

HTML code, it starts with `onload="hp()"`

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="140" height="10" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="button" value="Punch" onclick="punch()"/>
```

Comment: Is there a javascript error? You can see it at the lower left side of the browser, the yellow triangle?

Comment: Where/When are you calling `hp()` ? At that time the canvas node is ready?

Comment: There's no Error, I used a "Onload" to call `hp()`.
I've tried putting a Interval on the button then `clearinterval` at the end of the `hp()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `hp` function inside the `punch` function:

```
function punch() {
    health -= 1; 
    hp();
}
```

You also need to clear the canvas before adding a smaller rectangle, so add a call to the canvas `clearRect` method in the `hp` function:

```
function hp() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0);

    grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
    grd.addColorStop(0.2, "#F4710E");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "green");

    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); //<-- this
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, (health / 100) * 140, 10); //h changed to health
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = health + "/" + totalhealth; //h changed to health
}
hp(); //put this in the onload function, to initialize the health bar
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/9CrfA/4/)

Comment: That works for updating the "demo" but I need to update "myCanvas" too

Comment: @user3268382 Yeah, I missed that. Fixed now. See the updated fiddle

Comment: You prob still want to call hp() when the page loads as well, so that the gradient-bar can show a full 100%

Comment: @C.S. You're right, I've added that to the answer. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/9CrfA/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved so much headaches hahah :P